# Преобразование в 16 с.с

Tags: java, md5

Я писал консольную программку для шифрования полученной строки. После написания, я заметил, что зашифрованная строка *(полученный массив байтов)*  выглядит не так как мне нужно, а именно она выглядит так : `63-64-89-84-16-121-1173-844338107-81-108-72-79`, мне нужно получить эту строку в таком виде `3fc0a7acf087f549ac2b266baf94b8b1`, т.е. в 16-ом представлении

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md5_cy = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        String str = new String("qwerty123");
        byte[] bytes = md5_cy.digest(str.getBytes());
            for (byte V : bytes)
                System.out.print(V);
    }
}
```

` И такой вопрос: **Как полученный массив байтов привести в 16-й вид?**

Comment: посмотрите вот тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/how-to-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представить массив байт как hex-строку можно через [DatatypeConverter:printHexBinary](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printHexBinary(byte[])):

```
MessageDigest md5_cy = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
String str = "qwerty123";
byte[] bytes = md5_cy.digest(str.getBytes());

String hex = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
System.out.println(hex);               // 3FC0A7ACF087F549AC2B266BAF94B8B1
System.out.println(hex.toLowerCase()); // 3fc0a7acf087f549ac2b266baf94b8b1
```